# Loop through a table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a table `x` which has columns `y` and `z` it has **10** rows of data.

I then have a table-valued function `getDetails(y,z)` which takes values stored in table `x` in columns `y` and `z` to return a table `tb` with three columns.

I need to write a **tsql** query that loops values from table `x` through  function `getDetails(y,z)`to return one row per set of values `y` and `z`from table `x` in this case table `tb` should have **10** rows.

This is what I have so far which returns one row only each time I run it.

```
DECLARE @y NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @z NVARCHAR(2);

SELECT @y =y FROM x

SElECT @z =z FROM x


SELECT * from getDetails(@y,@z)
```

This returns

```
       col1      col2     col3
       ---------------------
row1   Lorem     Ipsum     Sit
```

//UPDATE
If anyone has an idea how I can use temp tables to achieve this please let me know

Comment: Don't think about this as "looping." Think of it as you want to retrieve the values from the function for the set of rows in an input table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call user defined function for every row of table x. you dont need looping, you can go for set based operations itself.

Below I am creating table user defined function, which returns a table with 3 columns.

```sql
create FUNCTION dbo.testtableresult(@a int)
returns table as
return
select @a+1 as a1, @a+2 as a2, @a+3 as a3
```

I am loading two rows into table variable and then calling the user defined function for each row.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(a int)

INSERT INTO @table values(1),(2)

SELECT t.a, t1.a1, t1.a2, t1.a3
FROM @table as t
CROSS APPLY dbo.testtableresult(t.a) as t1
```

```
+---+----+----+----+
| a | a1 | a2 | a3 |
+---+----+----+----+
| 1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
| 2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |
+---+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to getting all of the results at once, I would use `CROSS APPLY` here.

```
SELECT
  d.col1,
  d.col2,
  d.col3
FROM x
CROSS APPLY dbo.getDetails (x.y, x.z) AS d;
```

This will return the complete data set all at once. You could also add `x.y` and `x.z` to the `SELECT` clause if you needed/wanted those values in your results.